# Why do I get an error by starting my firebase project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wrote a very simple script (Python) to load data from Google Firebase. For this I downloaded firebase with ***sudo pip install python-firebase*** on my Raspberry. But when I start my script, I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File"...", line 2, in <module>
    from firebase import firebase
  File"/usr/local/python3.7/dist-packages/firebase/__init__.py", line 3
    from .async import process_pool
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The script I wrote is certainly not the problem, because I got it from the Internet and there I found the same code on different pages.

I have researched on the Internet, but can not find a real solution to this problem. I read on one page that it MAY be related to the Python version(3.7.3)... Is that possible in your view? Did I forget anything else to download (I only downloaded firebase as I mentioned above)? Does anyone know the solution or had the same problem?

Thanks in advance